# How do I manage a dynamic, changing main menu in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm writing a document based application in wxPython, by which I mean that the user can have open multiple documents at once in multiple windows or tabs. There are multiple kinds of documents, and the documents can all be in different "states", meaning that there should be different menu options available in the main menu.

I know how to disable and enable menu items using the `wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI` event, but I can't figure out how to pull off a main menu that changes structure and content drastically based on which document that currently has focus. One of my main issues is that the main menu is created in the top level window, and it has to invoke methods in grand children and great grand children that haven't even been created yet.

---

Contrived example; when a document of type "JPEG" is open, the main menu should look like:

```
File      Edit      Compression     Help
```

And when the user switches focus (CTRL+Tab) to a document of type "PDF", the main menu should change to:

```
File      Edit      PDF     Publish     Help
```

And the "Edit" menu should contain some different options from when the "JPEG" document was in focus.

---

Current I'm just creating the menu in a function called `create_main_menu` in the top level window, and the document panels have no control over it. What would be necessary to pull off the kind of main menu scheme I describe above, specifically in wxPython?

Comment: Are you creating all the layout programmatically? Just an idea, but maybe if you were using something like xrced (which generally makes things easier) you could create several menus and only show the one you need.

Comment: @Marian: I'm creating the layout programatically in this project, mainly because I dislike using WYSIWYG tools before I know how they work on a basic level. I have written a few functions for speeding up the creation of menus and toolbars though, so there's not much boilerplate code. That's not really the issue though, I'm more curious about how to dynamically change the main menu's structure based on what document is currently active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out a pretty clean way to do this. First of all I create my "base" main menu bar, which contains the *File* and *Help* menu items. Then I defined a class `EditorPanel` than is a subclass of `wx.Panel` and defined the methods `bind_main_menu_bar` and `release_main_menu_bar`. The first of those methods receives the main menu bar when the panel is focused, and adds some items to it. Here is one of my implementations:

```
def bind_main_menu_bar(self, main_menu_bar):
    main_frame = wx.GetApp().GetTopWindow()

    self.main_menu_bar = main_menu_bar

    # Create the edit menu.
    self.edit_menu = edit_menu = shared.create_menu([
        (const.ID_UNDO, self.LABEL_UNDO_EMPTY),
        (const.ID_REDO, self.LABEL_REDO_EMPTY)
    ])

    # Create the tools menu.
    self.tools_menu = tools_menu = shared.create_menu([
        (const.ID_SELECT_ADDRESS_COLUMNS, 'Select address columns...'),
        (),
        (const.ID_VALIDATE_ADDRESSES, 'Validate selected addresses'),
        (const.ID_VALIDATE_ALL_ADDRESSES, 'Validate all addresses')
    ])

    # Bind some menu event handlers to the main frame.
    main_frame.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_menu)
    main_frame.Bind(wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI, self.on_menu_update)

    # Insert the new menus into the main menu bar.
    main_menu_bar.Insert(1, edit_menu, 'Edit')
    main_menu_bar.Insert(2, tools_menu, 'Tools')
```

Now, when that editor panel is opened, the main menu receives an Edit menu and a Tools menu that is bound to event handlers in the `EditorPanel`, which is incredibly handy. When the editor loses focus, the `release_main_menu_bar` method is called, which should restore the main menu bar to it's original state. This is counterpart of the code above:

```
def release_main_menu_bar(self):
    main_frame = wx.GetApp().GetTopWindow()

    # Unbind the menu event handlers from the main frame.
    main_frame.Unbind(wx.EVT_MENU, handler=self.on_menu)
    main_frame.Unbind(wx.EVT_UPDATE_UI, handler=self.on_menu_update)

    # Remove the edit and tools menu from the main menu bar.
    self.main_menu_bar.Remove(1)
    self.main_menu_bar.Remove(1)

    # Reset the fields used for the menu.
    self.edit_menu = None
    self.tools_menu = None
    self.main_menu_bar = None
```

So every editor that wants to edit the main menu just has to subclass those two methods and they have full control. The main frame will monitor when the user switches between editors and call the methods accordingly. The biggest problem was to figure out when the editor panel receives and loses focus, which is the topic of another question of mine: [How do I monitor when wx.Panel receives and loses focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13675457/388916)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way to do it with the standard wx.Menu is to destroy and recreate the entire menubar. You might be able to Hide it though. Either way, I think it would be easiest to just put together a set of methods that creates each menubar on demand. Then you can destroy one and create the other.

You might also take a look at FlatMenu since it is pure Python and easier to hack.