# How do I monitor when wx.Panel receives and loses focus?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a class called `Editor` which is a subclass of `wx.Panel`. Only one `Editor` instance can be the "active" one at any point in time, and I want to monitor when they receive and lose focus so that I can make adjustments to the main menu. How do I do this?

---

#### What I've tried

- I have tried to listen to the `wx.EVT_ACTIVATE` event, but it apparently only triggers on frames and dialogs, not panels.
- All the editors are added to a `wx.aui.AuiNotebook` instance, so I tried listening to the `wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED` event, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. Panels don't have an aspect of "focus", so the solution has to be implemented at a higher level. Since all my `Editor` instances are members of an `wx.aui.AuiNotebook`, I can listen for the tab changes to decide when the editors are losing and receiving focus.

The event for listening to `wx.aui.AuiNotebook` page changes is `wx.aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED`, and the event object has the properties `Selection` and `OldSelection` to figure out which tab was previously active, and which tab is now active:

```
def on_notebook_page_changed(self, event):
    new_page = self.notebook.GetPage(event.Selection)

    if event.OldSelection > -1:
        old_page = self.notebook.GetPage(event.OldSelection)
    else:
        old_page = new_tab

    # ...
```